# Extracting point for polygons from shapefile - not working

Tags: qgis, geometry-conversion

I am trying to extract the lat long points for the polygons from a shapefile. I have followed the directions from the following links:

[Getting list of coordinates for points in layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/get-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-a-layer)

[How to extract geo data out of a polygon shapefile into CSV KWT](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82919/how-to-extract-geo-data-out-of-a-polygon-shape-file-into-csv-kwt)

Example output:

```
OBJECTID    AREA    PERIMETER   AGENCY  NAME    REVDATE SQMILES Shape_Leng Shape_Area
1   0   0       Zone1   11/19/2014  0   237658.615  1531052792
2   0   0       Zone2   11/19/2014  0   739330.0369 7625960825
3   201487008   72063.20313 PF  Zone3   11/19/2014  231.6181139 985159.932 5260739790
4   0   0       Zone4   11/19/2014  0   1192796.221 15149531125
5   0   0       Zone5   11/19/2014  0   2040909.712 22577444695
```

So does this mean there are no lat/longs to extract?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24442/how-do-i-convert-a-polygon-into-a-point

Comment: I think your word 'point' should be vertices/node

Comment: I need the points that represent each polygon and there are 5 polygons.

Comment: convert to centroids vector>geomtery tools>polygon centroids will give you a point with attributes

Comment: Vector -> Geomtry Tools -> Extract Nodes  -seems to pull out the parts I need. I now have to figure out the right lat/long conversion it seens to be in FEET or MILES - not decimal degrees. I picked WGS 84, but I may need to use the Project CRS - yes indeed!

Comment: Should I be using NAD 27 Northern Colorado vs WGS 84? I am in Northern Colorado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Extract Nodes** will extract the lat/long points from all the polygons to a new shape file, then right click on this new layer and select `SaveAs...`, then build the `csv` file. Using the CRS layer from the project will automatically convert the points to the desired output - based on the projects CRS projection. Each were labeled with a polygon name, so separating them out was possible.