# georeferenced raster coordinates

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

In QGIS 1.8 I have two rasters derived from the same multi-band tif image

1. ndvi - each pixel contains NDVI values. Using
   /Plugin/Analysis Point Sampling tool
   a new vector layer is created and the NDVI values of selected pixels are saved in the attribute table of this new layer. All is OK here.
2. geo
   a georeferenced raster of the same multi-band photo

How do I get the coordinates of the same pixels from raster (2) geo?

I would like to store them into the same attribute table where the NDVI values are.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please reword your thread title to a question which contains enough information for future readers who might come here looking for the same problem.

Comment: QGIS 1.8 is used

Answer (score 1):

[How to get Shapefile point coordinates into .xls?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50128/how-to-get-shapefile-point-coordinates-into-xls)

Following the  directions in the above post, merely
@vector layer containing the (NDVI, these may be different) values of the selected pixels go to

> Vector>Geometry Tools>Export/Add Geometry columns
>   enter the vector layer containing, the attribute table where the coordinates are to be added. click OK. This attribute table reads two new columns now, e.g.

wkt_geom    riba-ndvi-  XCOORD  YCOORD

POINT(8378.111080 -1838.011980) 0.25517 8378.11108  -1838.01198

POINT(8378.111080 -1758.011980) 0.30189 8378.11108  -1758.01198

POINT(3178.111080 -5558.011980) 0.19718 3178.11108  -5558.01198

some further clarification is required
How do XCOORD   YCOORD relate to lati/long?
When the original multi-band raster is georeferenced 4 pixels are selected from the canvas and the coordinates are selected from the multi-band *.tif raster. All thety look like

X=25.6341644    Y=42.2355833

These are real coordinates showing the exact location of the object.