# Import shapefile then export coordinates

Tags: qgis

I have received some shapefiles which I believe are from ArcGIS.  Each "file" consists of a number of physical files, e.g.

```
kv_27.dbf
kv_27.shp
kv_27.shp.xml
kv_27.shx
```

I need to extract the coordinates from these files.  I am trying to use QGIS and the instructions here:

[How to get Shapefile point coordinates into .xls?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50128/how-to-get-shapefile-point-coordinates-into-xls?newreg=3dc13d84e4d5487597e686fc731126c5)

I am opening the files using Add layer >> Add vector layer

My first question is which file or files should I open?

When I try to carry out the command

Vector >> Geometry tools >> Add/Export Geometry Columns

Once I click OK I get the error message:

Currently QGIS doesn't allow simultaneous access from different threads to the same datasource. Make sure your layer's attribute tables are closed. Continue?

Neither option (yes/no) provides the coordinates.

Could someone explain what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should add the `.shp` file. The warning is not an error message, just continue.

Comment: @Vince - With Iant's help I have exported the attribute table but all that is included is 
ident    area         PERIMETER :
27  459078.1223 3921.444532

I believe this means the attempt to add the coordinates has failed? Correct?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the save as option and select csv as the output format.

Comment: Hi @Iant Thanks - that exports the attribute table for the layer as required.  Thanks again P

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this strictly answers the original question but it has resolved my problem which was to extract the coordinates into a file I could use.

Firstly I did as suggested and opened the .shp file as a vector layer (Add layer >> Add vector layer)

Then I enabled the MMQGIS plugin

Finally I selected MMQGIS >>Import/Export >>Geometry Export to CSV File

This produces two files 1) an attribute file 2) a nodes file

The nodes file contains the coordinates for the shape

Thanks for everyone's help.

P

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It worked perfectly for me as well.